# How to automate chromedriver download?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

This was the code I used earlier to download chromedriver using python where the current version is cross checked with the latest available version and downloads the same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import zipfile
import wget
import subprocess
import os
import shutil


CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Driver_Path\chromedriver.exe"
CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
LATEST_DRIVER_URL = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"


def download_latest_version(version_number):
    print("Attempting to download latest driver online......")
    download_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + version_number + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"
    # download zip file
    latest_driver_zip = wget.download(download_url, out=CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER)
    # read & extract the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(latest_driver_zip, 'r') as downloaded_zip:
        # You can chose the folder path to extract to below:
        downloaded_zip.extractall(path=CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER)
    # delete the zip file downloaded above
    os.remove(latest_driver_zip)


def check_driver():
    # run cmd line to check for existing web-driver version locally
    cmd_run = subprocess.run("chromedriver --version",
                             capture_output=True,
                             text=True)
    # Extract driver version as string from terminal output
    local_driver_version = cmd_run.stdout.split()[1]
    print(f"Local driver version: {local_driver_version}")
    # check for latest chromedriver version online
    response = requests.get(LATEST_DRIVER_URL)
    online_driver_version = response.text
    print(f"Latest online chromedriver version: {online_driver_version}")
    if local_driver_version == online_driver_version:
        print("Latest chromedriver already present")
        return True

    else:
        download_latest_version(online_driver_version)
        print("Latest chromedriver file downloaded")



check_driver()
```

But now the url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE is stuck at version 114 and now we are at version 117. So, this code will no longer work. Now, everytime I have to download the chromedriver file manually if there is a version update. Is there anyway I can automate this download process?

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to find the version you want from this site: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

It also provides JSON endpoint for automation script to get available versions: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing#json-api-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade Selenium to version 4.11.0 or higher to use the built in [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/), it will handle the driver-browser matching, and then just use

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```